# Performselector not call in NSThread

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a problem that i want to call a function when one of my functions that is running into a seperate thread comes to an end:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(fetchFeaturedFreeApps) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

here is my `fetchFeaturedFreeApps` function

```
-(void)fetchFeaturedFreeApps
{
    ////all my code
    [self performSelector:@selector(closeView) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.0];
}
```

My problem is that the close view methods doesnt run after the 4 seconds.

Hoew if i call the  fetchFeaturedFreeApps method with perform selector then my closeview metod is called properly.

Your valuable help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to run any UI or view update code in a selector that runs on the main thread, not in a background thread. Use `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` and place a timer in that selector to fire after four seconds, which closes your view.